# Make Text Bolder By selecting radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I m new to jquery,I am supposed to do the simple task.If i click on the radio button means the text along with that radio button has to be bolded.please help me with this one.My HTML Markup is here

```html
<form role="form">
    <p><b>What concerns you most as you manage your business?</b>(Select all that apply.)</p>
    <div class="radio active">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="optradio">IT infrastructure alignment with business goals and growth<img /></label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="optradio">Controlling capital and expense<img /></label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="optradio">Managing financial risk<img /></label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="optradio">Data security and privacy<img /></label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="optradio">Flexibility of services to meet customer needs<img /></label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="optradio">Political climate for business<img /></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group radio">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="optradio">
        </label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" placeholder="Other(please specify)" id="comment"></textarea>
    </div>
</form>
```

And my jquery code is here

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(".radio label input").click(function() {
        $('.radio').each(function(event) {
            if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
                $(this).css("font-family", "helveticabold");
                $('.radio').removeClass('active');

                if ($(this).next().hasClass('radio'))
                    $(this).next().addClass('active');
                else
                    $('.radio:last-child').addClass('active');
                return false;
            }
        });
    });

});
```

I know it needs small changes in code please help me out guys

Comment: What is `<img />` inside `label`, you don't need this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to use `each` as only one `radio` can be selected.

This will do:

Javascript:

```
$('.radio').on('click', function() {
    $('.bold').removeClass('bold');
    $(this).addClass('bold');
});
```

CSS:

```
.bold {
    font-weight: 800;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/3zzaLre0/

Answer (score 5):

You can use $(this) selector for that

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) { 
    $("input[type='radio']").click(function() {
        $("input[type='radio']").parent().css('font-weight','');
        $(this).parent().css('font-weight','bold');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form role="form">
    <p><b>What concerns you most as you manage your business?</b>(Select all that apply.)</p>
    <div class="radio active">
        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio"><span>IT infrastructure alignment with business goals and growth<img /></label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio"><span>Controlling capital and expense<img /></label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">Managing financial risk<img /></label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">Data security and privacy<img /></label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio"><span>Flexibility of services to meet customer needs<img /></label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio"><span>Political climate for business<img /></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio"></label><span>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" placeholder="Other(please specify)" id="comment"></textarea>
    </div>
</form>
```